# QSS style file vs Designer style

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I'm using a png as a QPushButton background. Style Sheet code:

```
QPushButton
{
    border: none;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-image: url(":/icons/GitHub-Mark-Light.png");
}

QPushButton:hover
{
    border-image: url(":/icons/GitHub-Mark-Light-Hover.png");
}

QPushButton:pressed
{
    border-image: url(":/icons/GitHub-Mark-Light.png");
}
```

If I set this code in Qt Designer then the png background is transparent where it needs to be.
But when I set the same code in my CSS file png transparency is being lost. 
How do I fix this and use my png through CSS?

Comment: Setting the style in the Designer is like setting the style on the [object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) (and its child objects), while QSS style file is global for all objects (depending on what object loads it). It can make the cascading or inheritance of the style different, but I don't see why you get this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know why the style is applied differently in the case of Qt Designer or CSS file, but apparently Qt Designer somehow overrides the parent style (the style of the parent window) in a special way. 
I solved the problem by transferring the style of the parent window to the CSS file too.